# I cut into a chimney to build a fireplace. What should I use to build the bottom of the fireplace

Tags: masonry

What kind of corrugated metal should I use for a fireplace bottom. It's a masonry brick fireplace

Comment: Why use corrugated metal for a masonry fireplace? Where could it be installed?

Comment: No kind of corrugated metal. It's a masonry fireplace, and corrugated metal is not masonry. Firebrick is the material you need here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the chimney is used for another fuel/heating source, quite possible you have made a big boo-boo.  Most places it is one chimney per heat/fuel source.  Usually a fireplace will use a chimney, you don't make a fireplace in a chimney.